# Fastest way to query from large XML files, real time, in python

Tags: python, xml, bigdata

I need to search through a mix of XML files with size between 10-200MB for a particular string that is always at the same level of an XML file, underneath the same tags.

If I find this particular string, then I need to gather other data from the tree. Unfortunately the value of interest is nested deeply in the data. Not every file contains this tag. And sometimes the tag will contain the query value, sometimes it will not.

```
<foo>
    <fun2>
        <bla>Same level useless value with different tag</bla>
    </fun2>
    <fun>

        <bar>
            <maybeofinterest>Not of interest</maybeofinterest>
            <maybeofinterest>Check the whole tree</maybeofinterest>
        </bar>
    </fun>
<foo>
```

I am currently using a simple ElementTree object to hold my XML trees and it is very slow on the larger files (considering lxml instead). It is also a terrible waste when the query item of interest is not even in the file, then the whole tree is tossed.

Is there a fast way to only query for a specific tag? Or is dumb line by line file search the way to go? If the block has the wrong tag I can skip the entire block, I was hoping for a way to take advantage of this fact.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).